# Bootstrap dropdown select style like multiple select combo box

Tags: css, select, bootstrap-4, styles

Is it possible to have bootstrap select style the same way as bootstrap multiple select? I mean dropdown select looking like combo box.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is in size attribute. So simple :)